# FileUpload in FormView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload, formview

I have a problem regarding with add an image URL within a database.I'm using fileupload method within formview in ASP.Net.And I have a table called duyurular
which can be record a image URL.BTW,I'm using SQL Server Database.
My question is;I'm doing the process update,delete and to make an announcement  in the FormView.I can upload those images within folder called "img"  with FileUpload.
However,I want to record it within database as well.when to add within database another those infos,there are no the image URL.
Finally,I can't add the image URL within database.

Here is my code;

```
public partial class panel_yoneticipaneli : System.Web.UI.Page
{

FileUpload dosya, dosya1;
//TextBox t1, t2, t3;
//Button btn;
SqlConnection con;
static string str = "Data Source=SERT;Initial Catalog=Mmakina;Integrated Security=True";
string yol = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dosya = (FileUpload)FormView2.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    dosya1 = (FileUpload)FormView2.FindControl("FileUpload2");
   // btn = (Button)FormView2.FindControl("ResimKaydetButonu");
    //t1 = (TextBox)FormView2.FindControl("DuyuruBaslikTextBox");
    //t2 = (TextBox)FormView2.FindControl("DuyuruIcerikTextBox");
    //t3 = (TextBox)FormView2.FindControl("DuyuruTarihiTextBox");

    Label1.Visible = false;
    if (Session["KullaniciID"]!=null)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand sorgu = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Kullanici WHERE KullaniciAdi=@KullaniciAdi", con);
        sorgu.Parameters.Add("@KullaniciAdi", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["KullaniciAdi"];
          con.Open();
        SqlDataReader oku = sorgu.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        Label1.Visible = true;
        while (oku.Read())
        {
           Label1.Text = oku["KullaniciAdi"].ToString();

        }

    }
    else {
        Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
    }


}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Roles.DeleteCookie();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("giris.aspx");

}

protected void btn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
    try
    {
        if (dosya.HasFile)
        {
           dosya.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + dosya.FileName);
           System.Drawing.Image resim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + dosya.FileName);
           yol = "img/" + dosya.FileName;
           resim.Dispose();
           DbUpload();


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}



public void DbUpload() {
    try {
                    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERT;Initial Catalog=Mmakina;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand("insert into Duyuru(DuyuruResmi) values(@DuyuruResmi)", sc);
        scom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DuyuruResmi", dosya.FileName);

        scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
    }catch(Exception p){
        p.Message.ToString();
    }
}


 protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
    {

        if (dosya.HasFile)
        {
           dosya.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + dosya.FileName);
           yol = "img/" + dosya.FileName;
           Response.Write("Fileupload çalışıyor...");
         DbUpload();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
  }
```

thanks in advance for all comments you can share.

Comment: Always try to post relevant code and format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Formview `ItemInserting Event`, where you can pass in the built URL.

```
protected void frmAsset_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
   if (dosya.HasFile)
    {
       dosya.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + dosya.FileName);
       e.NewValues["URL"] = "img/" + dosya.FileName;
    }
 }
```

Comment: -First of all,thanks for your interesting.But,that's gives me the error and the page does not open.

Comment: Compiler Error Message:CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewUpdateEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Values' and no extension method 'Values' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewUpdateEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Selo; Sorry, that's used in ItemUpdating event. just missed it. here it should be NewValues, I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you just upload the image name without specifying the full URL, and you can save the image base path in the web.config like `'<add key="ImagesBasePath" value="/img" />'` so you can change the path were you have your images and you can control the view of this image by concatenating the Image name to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesBasePath"]` so this will be better.